# ¿Por qué aparece el mensaje <app> (proceso xxxxx) se cerró con el código 0 en la consola?

Tags: c#

Justo hoy me inicio en el mundo de la programación aprendiendo C# en Visual Studio 2019 (que es el que me ha recomendado el profesor). En mi primera línea de código en la que simplemente quiero mostrar por pantalla una frase, me aparece además esta línea que no comprendo el porqué:

> C:\Users\asanm\source\repos\PrimeraAplicacion\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\PrimeraAplicacion.exe (proceso 15172) se cerró con el código 0.

A continuación el codigo:

```
``
using System;
``
namespace PrimeraAplicacion
``
    class Program
    ``
        static void Main(string[] args)
        ``
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            ``
```

Comment: Así como está escrita la pregunta, da como para _adivinar_. Para evitar esto, pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de tu código. Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: ¿Esos _backticks_ (`) también están en tu código? ¿Y las llaves?

Comment: Todos los programas deben devolver un número entero para indicar cómo terminó la ejecución. El 0 significa que fue normalmente. Ese número es el que devuelve la función`main`. Aunque si se llama explícitamente a la función [`Exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit) se usará el entero que recibe la función como código de salida.

Comment: retorno 0: un retorno 0 significa que el programa se ejecutará correctamente e hizo lo que estaba destinado a hacer. [codigo 0](https://es.acervolima.com/return-0-vs-return-1-en-c/#:~:text=retorno%200%3A%20un%20retorno%200,lo%20que%20se%20pretend%C3%ADa%20hacer.)

Comment: @Mateo Si Main esté retornando un void, ¿es posible que devuelva cero?

Comment: @padaleiana [si el tipo es `void` implícitamente el código de salida es 0](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/11857). Si hay algún error o se llama a la función `Exit`, el número que recibe como parámetro será el código de salida.

Comment: ¿Te aparece algo como [esto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97hsL.png)?  Si lo que quieres es quitar ese mensaje, reformula la pregunta para que sea mejor recibida. Es muy importante hacer la pregunta correcta.

Comment: Entendido @Mateo (Y)